# How to display/print emojis from unicode in tkinter python 3.8

Tags: json, tkinter, emoji, python-3.8, tkinter-canvas

I'm working on an algorithm that can display an emoji from a json file in tkinter, but I can't seem to figure it out? I've tried various solutions, but none of them seem to work? I've tried printing it regularly and even using the emoji module, but both give me a werid looking symbol? I've done a bunch of research trying to find a solution but haven't really found one that works? I'm using windows 10, and I know that is a part of the reason why I can't display emojis on the Python IDE. But does anyone have any ideas or suggestions of a way to solve this?

I'm trying to take a string from a json file that looks something like this "\u00f0\u009f\u00a6\u008b" and display it as its corresponding emoji, something like this "" and not a werid looking symbol. I would like it to look like an actual emoji. Any ideas or suggestions of a way to solve this, please?? Thank you x

Comment: Are you sure the unicode used is correct? For character like "☺", the unicode is `"\U0000263a"`, not `"\u263a"`.

Comment: @acw1668 , Yes, It is. That's the Unicode that's in the json file. The Unicode I gave above is for a butterfly.

Comment: For a butterfly, try `"\U0001F98B"` instead.  Note that it is shown in platform which supports, like Windows 10.  It does not work in Windows 7.

Comment: @acw1668 , Yeah, but that's not how it is in the json file. I have so many different emojis in there. I can't change the code of every single one of them? Is there any way that It can display it from that? Also? The main problem I'm running into is that when they get printed, they're just symbols and not actual emojis.

Comment: @acw1668 , Hey? Do you have any ideas on how to convert/decode UTF-8 hex codes to unicode?

Comment: No I don't know. As I said in my comment, it works when `"\U0001F98B"` is used.  Also `emoji.emojize(":butterfly:")` works when `emoji` module is used.